# AJAX only works one time

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I did a modal with a login form and the submit through a POST AJAX request. I only can login one time, when I logout and try to login again the error message of AJAX request is this **(CSRF failed)**:

```
Prohibido (403)
Verificación CSRF fallida. Solicitud abortada
```

The login only works again if I refresh the whole page pressing F5. After the success on the login I refresh only the header, not the whole page. My refresh code is this:

```
$('#update-' + idToUpdate).load(' #' + idToUpdate);
```

**EDIT:**
**I discovered that the CSRF token only works one time after a success request. I have to generate a new token for the form to work again, and this token only get update if I refresh the whole page pressing F5, and that is just what I do not want to do.**

Any solution for this problem? I would not like to do AJAX requests to update the CSRF token, that is not secure.

Comment: Can you please mention how exactly are you creating the CSRF token ? Is it through the template variable or through the js function mentioned in the docs ? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: `<form ... > </form>{% csrf_token %}` that is how Django works. It is equivalent to an input hidden with the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Insert all the ids of the forms with the CSRF token in my function `$('#update-' + idToUpdate).load(' #' + idToUpdate);` after the success request. This do a partial async F5 refresh of the forms, so all the CSRF tokens get update and I can do new requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the CSRF token by JS itself:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
     }
     return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

This will create a new CSRF token everytime you call the function and you won't be required to refresh the page.

For more info check out : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: That code takes the current CSRF token's value but does not refresh it or create a new one. I tried with that code from the official documentation, but it does not work. 
The objective of that code along with the other one that appears in the official documentation is to obtain the current value of the token from the cookie and insert it in the header of the ajax request. If you want send new success requests you need refresh the token.